# Passing parameter to another JSP page

Tags: java, jsp

I'm doing a webapp in Java/JSP with fellow students and I have a problem. There is a form in file *login.jsp* like this:

```
<form id="signin" action="/login" autocomplete="off" method="post">
            <p2>Login</p2>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="username"/>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="password"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
            <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and I want to somehow pass the username to main JSP page which form above redirects to when the login is succesful (form doesn't use WebServlet).

Is there a way to do this by getting the parameter in another page or setting the username as session attribute after the form is submitted?

Comment: Your form action submits it to login Servlet.  Yes, you could set username into the session scope there(if login succeeds). That would make it accessible throughout your web app.

Comment: store it in the session.